# how to use CSS clip-path in IE?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

In html,

```
<div id='box'><img src='img.png' id='img' /></div>
```

CSS,

```
    width: 370px;
    height: 372px;

  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%, 0% 0%, 50% 41%);
  -o-clip-path: polygon(100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%, 0% 0%, 50% 41%);
   clip-path: polygon(100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%, 0% 0%, 50% 41%);
```

it work on browser except IE

how to use clip-path in internet explorer?

can i need another css code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, Clip Path is not supported in IE at all, as shown [here](http://caniuse.com/#search=clip-path).

You could search for a polyfill, however, I haven't found one of real note on a [quick search](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=clip%20path%20polyfill).

If you truly want a mask over the image and have it working cross-browser, you'll have to put the mask on the image with an image editor.

Comment: Edge is a joke though. I thought Microsoft finally did something good but that browser is still a piece of... I mean is a joke.